# Is there a way to render a view outside of ng-view only when ng-view gets rendered?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-view

I've got user navigation in a partial loaded using `ng-include` that's outside of the `ng-view`. I'm also authenticating users and prefetching almost all data necessary for any controller and view in `route.resolve`.

The issue is that the user navigation partial is displayed using `ng-show="currentUser"` directive and so when user signs in and `currentUser` gets set, the navigation partial is shown, but the new view is still waiting to be displayed till all data is fetched in `route.resolve`. The same situation happens when user signs out - the navigation bar is hidden and the old view is still displayed before user gets redirected and the page for signed out users is displayed.

Is there a way to somehow "link" (re)rendering of the main view (`ng-view`) and a partial outside of that view? The only other idea I have is to move `ng-include` directive that loads navigation bar into every template, which is rather annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make use of the events fired by `ng-view` (`$viewContentLoaded`, emitted, see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView)) and the `$route` serice (`$routeChangeSuccess`, broadcasted, see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)).

The controller of user navigation partial must set a flag controlling the visibility of the UI depending on the arrival of the appropriate event *and* the state of the model (`currentUser` probably).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll have to add a controller for it, but it may be enough to start listening for one of the events you mentioned when currentUser is set or deleted and update the flag when it's emitted. I'll try it tomorrow. Might need angular-once for that...